# SerialPort and the BSOD

Tags: c#, concurrency, serial-port, bsod

I've written some C# code that checks whether a device is present on any SerialPort by issuing a command on the port and listening for a reply. When I just set the port speed, open the port, get the serial stream and start processing, it works 100% of the time. However, some of our devices work at different speeds and I am trying to probe for a device at various speeds to autonegotiate a connection as well as detect device presence.

When I do all this in a single thread there are no problems. However, 3s timeout at ten speeds is 30s per serial port, and there may be several. Hence the desire to probe all ports concurrently.

Sometimes this works. Sometimes Vista bluescreens. When I use threads to probe all the ports simultaneously it nearly always bluescreens. When I force everything to run in one thread it never happens.

A USB-serial Prolific PL-2303 adaptor is in use with x64 drivers.

---

@Vinko - thanks for the tip on reading minidumps.

As near as I can tell, the crux of the problem is that by starting a new asynchronous I/O operation *from a different thread* it is possible to give a whole new meaning to overlapped I/O, inducing a race condition inside the driver. Since the driver executes in kernel mode, **BLAM!**

## Epilogue

Except for kicking off, don't use BeginXxx outside of the callback handler and don't call BeginXxx until you've called EndXxx, because you'll induce a race condition in driver code that runs in kernel mode.

## Postscript

I have found that this also applies to socket streams.

Comment: you can use windbg on the minidumps to check the exact error, which will lead you to better searches

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having written Windows drivers for one of these sort of device once, my advice would be not to waste your time with WinDbg trying to prove what you already know - i.e. that the driver you're using is buggy.

If you can find a more up-to-date driver from the PL2302, then try that, but my recommendation is that if you have to use USB->Serial adaptors, the FTDI-based ones are the best.    (They're *not* the one I wrote the drivers for, either...)

Comment: The fault was mine. I induced a race condition. I agree that the driver should HANDLE the exception and not bluescreen the OS, but the bug was mine and it's fixed/

Comment: You're very charitable!  There's NOTHING you should be able to do in user-mode code which causes a blue-screen - the driver should be able to cope with every possible ordering of I/O requests without crashing.

Comment: Hell, drivers should not run in ring 0. But for performance reasons they do. The grace to accept what I cannot change, y'know?

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable "Automatic Restart" under System Properties\Advanced\Start and Recovery\Settings. Once you disable that, you can see the BSOD and look for the error message, e.g. IRQL_LESS_OR_EQUAL, by searching for that error name, you can usually narrow down to the source of the problem.

Btw, not many notebook comes with serial ports nowadays, so you must be using USB-Serial converter? If that's the case, the driver might have been an issue to start with, since most manufacturer wrote the serial port driver as virtual driver.

Comment: I've seen BSOD problems with iffy USB drivers before - that's exactly where I'd start looking.

Comment: It is a USB port and I am aware that such issues have been reported. I also know that end users will take the attitude that since some of their software works with the USB adaptor then all of it should, and I have to agree with them. As noted above it works when all occurs on one thread.

Comment: I have turned off auto restart per your advice. Currently I'm not getting bluescreens because I've rewritten to keep all handling of a port on the same thread, but if it recurs I will at least be able to peruse the message.

Answer (score 0):

BSOD usually means buggy drivers.

What kind of HW ports do you use? I've had BSODs with SiLabs CP21xx USB to Serial converters drivers.

Comment: I found the chipset manufacturer's website and will try other drivers. My options are limited due to the need for x64 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There are FTDI drivers that are stable under x64 vista and win7.  I second the person who said to use FTDI chipsets only.

Most of the cheap serial to usb dongles at the shops near me (Toronto, Canada) seem to be FTDI chips.  It's never on the box, so I buy one, and if it's good, I go buy a box full of them.

W